# Parsing Arraylist of type Class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using arraylist to hold my result set data from the database. My result set contains four rows. I'm using arraylist of object type. I'm able to save my data to arraylist. **But when I tried to print the data from arraylist it is printing the data from last object that is saved.** But when I tried to print the arraylist as it is it is printing four different objects. Please help me in printing the arraylist data.

**My Servlet:**

```
List<FMB_BOOKS> books = FMB_BOOKS.getBooks();                        
System.out.println("List from Books: " + books);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();         
Iterator<FMB_BOOKS> itr = books.iterator();
FMB_BOOKS results = new FMB_BOOKS();                      
out.println(books.toString());
for (FMB_BOOKS book : books) 
{
    System.out.println("Book ID from Books: " + book.getBookid());
    out.println(book.getBookid());
    out.println(book.getBookname());
    out.println(book.getAuthorname());
    out.println(book.getCategory());
    out.println(book.getLanguage());
    out.println(book.getYear());
    out.println(book.getPublisher());
    out.println(book.getCaption());
    out.println(book.getImage());               
}
```

**My Java Class:**

```
while (rs.next())
{
    FMB_BOOKS Obj_Books = new FMB_BOOKS();              
    System.out.println("Inside While Result Set");              
    FMB_BOOKS.setBookid(rs.getString("BOOK_ID"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setBookname(rs.getString("BOOK_NAME"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setAuthorname(rs.getString("AUTHOR_NAME"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setCaption(rs.getString("CAPTION"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setCategory(rs.getString("CATEGORY"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setYear(rs.getString("PUBLISHED_YEAR"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setPublisher(rs.getString("PUBLISHER"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setLanguage(rs.getString("LANGUAGE"));
    FMB_BOOKS.setImage(rs.getString("IMAGE"));        
    books.add(Obj_Books);

}
```

Comment: Obj_Books : com.uday.FMB_BOOKS@5658532
List from Books: [com.uday.FMB_BOOKS@3ac20b87, com.uday.FMB_BOOKS@3d816aab, com.uday.FMB_BOOKS@411d3688, com.uday.FMB_BOOKS@5658532]
Book ID: 4
Book ID: 4
Book ID: 4
Book ID: 4

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Are the fields in your `FMB_BOOKS` class `static` by any chance? Because you seem to be using static setters instead of the actual `Obj_Books` object you created.

Comment: Yes they are static

Comment: Well, then there is your error. Static fields belong to the class, not an instance/object. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class